# Django: Use a read-only database within django test suite

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing

In my Django project, I'm using two databases, one of which is my own PostgreSQL database where I have the read and write rights, and the other one is an external PostgreSQL database in which I only have **read-only** rights. By the way, both databases have their own respective models, they aren't the same in any way.

It works perfectly in the context of the project, I can access both databases. However when I use the Django test suite using `./manage.py test`, Django is trying to create a test database for the external database.

I don't want that, I want to be still able to access the external PostgreSQL database within the test suite without needing to create a test database on this external PostgreSQL database.

It also gives me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:323: RuntimeWarning:
Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid
running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed
(for example, when running tests).
Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database
and will use the first PostgreSQL database instead.
```

But I don't have access to the 'postgres' database in the external database and I don't want to run initialization queries against it.

Here is the configuration for the external **read-only** database connection:

```py
DATABASES["aact"] = {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "OPTIONS": {"options": "-c search_path=ctgov"},
    "NAME": AACT_DATABASE_NAME,
    "USER": AACT_DATABASE_USER,
    "PASSWORD": AACT_DATABASE_PASS,
    "HOST": AACT_DATABASE_HOST,
    "PORT": AACT_DATABASE_PORT,
    "TEST": {"NAME": AACT_DATABASE_NAME, "MIGRATE": False},
}
```

Comment: No one can help me ? :/

Answer (score 0):

on test you can choose any database which you want.

in settings.py, or, much better, local_settings.py:

```
import sys

DATABASES["aact"] = {...}
if 'test' in sys.argv:
   DATABASES["aact"] = {settings for fake database with write permissions}
```

other way - define your DbRouter.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers

```
class BaseRouter:
    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **__):
        return "db for read"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **__):
        return "db for write"
```

after that in settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['somethere.whereis.BaseRouter']
```

The first example if fast to start. The second help you to make tests better.

Comment: Do you want me to create a copy of the external database with write permissions? Because by doing so I also want to test the external database models, this means every time I want to run the tests I would want an exact copy at the given time. Due to the fact the external database is enormous, I don't really know if that's the best practice because it would add up to more than 30 minutes to load everything just because I want to access read-only data.

Comment: To test something you are don't need the newest database. You should runt test's. And i wrote you a second possibility: to write you can use other db.

Comment: For this example I need the newest external database, The test should fail if the newest external database is not the same as the snapshot of it, it is mandatory, not in terms of data differences but in terms of model differences mostly because I need to have model coherence. By the way, I don't really understand what you are saying to me. Do you fully understand my problem?